# CTE (common table expression) issue

Tags: sql

[image]

This is the data employee table
i am not able to understand why data from employee table gets deleted,
i have used delete on cte table not main table , then why data gets deleted from employee table.

can anyone help me on this.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Please [do not post images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: CTE is not a table, it exists only for current query. It doesn't make sense to delete from CTE alone: delete is propagated to the underlying table. Each DBMS has its own restrictions, but if they are met, delete affects a base table

Answer (score 0):

It is "by design"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
(Common table expressions can also be used with the SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and CREATE VIEW statements.)